# IT HIT WEBDAV Word Document Opens Read Only

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, webdav, ithit-webdav-server

The website we are developing uses IT HIT WebDAV to manage documents.

When the document accessed first time from http://website.com/document.docx, a dialog box pops up with options in it like OPEN/SAVE/SAVE AS.

I'm expecting this document open in MS-WORD instead of asking to save.

If the OPEN option selected from the popup dialog, the document downloads and opens in Word document as read-only. When the document closed and accessed again from the same URL, it works properly [opens DOC in the local system MS-WORD application]

The issue is first time it downloads and opens and subsequent time it opens in ms-word application. When it opens in ms-word app, the document works as expected.

Comment: And what did IT Hit support say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are clicking on web page and expecting the file to be opened in MS Word directly from WebDAV server?
To do this you need to use Java applet which will run MS Word passing it the URL to open.
But on Windows systems you can use ActiveXObject "SharePoint.OpenDocuments" in IE and "application/x-sharepoint" plugin in FF/Chrome/Safari browsers.
You can find working example here: http://ajaxbrowser.com/ ('Edit document' from context menu).

Comment: i supposed to click your post as ans. but clicked mine. re-selected the ans. :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
var openDocumentsObject = new ActiveXObject("SharePoint.OpenDocuments.3");
openDocumentsObject.EditDocument(url);
```

Note: url represents the location of docx.

Comment: It is better to use "SharePoint.OpenDocuments" - version will be detected automatically.

Comment: After much searching this worked for me also.  We are rolling our own WebDav server.